# Skipping multiple modules in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to enable Sonar on a fairly large code base that is built using Maven/tycho.
Thanks to the sonar-example on github, I'm able to exclude modules by listing them individually, however this is not really maintainable going forward.
Do you know if it is possible to use a regexp or an ant pattern in the skippedModules property.

Thanks,

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. This is a known limitation: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3947